# How to transfer ASP.NET session state objects?

Tags: asp.net, session-state, sessionid

In order to mitigate potential Session Fixation/Trapping attacks, we need to be able to transfer the ASP.NET session state from one session Id to another after a user successfully logs in.  A user has important session information before login that needs to be transferred, so we cannot just call Session.Abandon or Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "")) as all the session state is lost.  We can use System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager to call CreateSessionID() and then SaveSessionID() to generate a new ID, but again, the prior state is lost on the next request.  So my question is basically how to transfer/correlate session state from a pre-login session Id to a post-login session Id.

Comment: You have 6 questions with no accepted answers.  Please accept the best answer on some of your questions so people will be motivated to work on your problem.

Comment: Is it a requirement to start a new session when the user logs in? Sessions and Authentication are not related.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact problem with potential session fixation is that the session Id does not change after authentication.  We're not using forms auth to be able to leverage the presence of an auth token (which would in effect act like a new session Id after a successful login).

Comment: Thats what i said. Why can't you use the session any longer when the user logs in?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple articles and posts around that explain the potential issues with using Session state. The most obvious is problematic support for multi-server environments.

If you store the items that you're currently putting in Session[]in a database or use SQL-based sessions, "transferring" is simply a matter of associating a user or connection with a particular record set.

If you bypass the Session object and handle everything yourself, which is a trivial task if you want to maintain the simple Session[] key-value interface, you get a number of benefits, such as settings that persist between sessions and across applications (as long as they share a common database).

Comment: Due to the size of our code base, it would be a large task to refactor all the calls to HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value to use a custom session state manager.  Using the database is definitely an option to store the serialized objects temporarily, but it is considered a last resort.  I was looking for some way to store or cache the serialized objects temporarily using SessionState itself.  I looked for a way to create a placeholder session and transfer the objects, but couldn't find out how to do this.